# Delete specific lines in a text file using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to delete some specific lines of a text using VB.Net. I saw a solution [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=2667) however it is in VB6. The problem is, I am not really familiar with VB6. Can somebody help me?
This is the code from the link:

```
Public Function DeleteLine(ByVal fName As String, ByVal LineNumber As Long) _As Boolean
    'Purpose: Deletes a Line from a text file

    'Parameters: fName = FullPath to File
    '            LineNumber = LineToDelete

    'Returns:    True if Successful, false otherwise

    'Requires:   Reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

    'Example: DeleteLine("C:\Myfile.txt", 3)
    '           Deletes third line of Myfile.txt
    '______________________________________________________________


    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFSTR As Scripting.TextStream
    Dim ret As Long
    Dim lCtr As Long
    Dim sTemp As String, sLine As String
    Dim bLineFound As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If oFSO.FileExists(fName) Then
        oFSTR = oFSO.OpenTextFile(fName)
        lCtr = 1
        Do While Not oFSTR.AtEndOfStream
            sLine = oFSTR.ReadLine
            If lCtr <> LineNumber Then
                sTemp = sTemp & sLine & vbCrLf
            Else
                bLineFound = True

            End If
            lCtr = lCtr + 1
        Loop

        oFSTR.Close()
        oFSTR = oFSO.CreateTextFile(fName, True)
        oFSTR.Write(sTemp)

        DeleteLine = bLineFound
    End If


ErrorHandler:
    On Error Resume Next
    oFSTR.Close()
    oFSTR = Nothing
    oFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: How big is the file that contains the line to be deleted?

Comment: It's around 1KB to 2KB.

Comment: Then the answer from @David below is the best one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Dim delLine As Integer = 10
Dim lines As List(Of String) = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("infile.txt").ToList
lines.RemoveAt(delLine - 1) ' index starts at 0 
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("outfile.txt", lines)
```

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to add a `For` Loop for the code.

Comment: I was using FileSystem methods to work with text files (Such as FileOpen, FileClose), but it doesn't provide a way to manipulate the text files, except for appending to it. Your code is a very simple yet effective way to do any sort of manipulation to a text file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
    'This can also be the file that you read in
    Dim str As String = "sdfkvjdfkjv" & vbCrLf & "dfsgkjhdfj" & vbCrLf & "dfkjbhhjsdbvcsdhjbvdhs" & vbCrLf & "dfksbvashjcvhjbc"

    Dim str2() As String = str.Split(vbCrLf)

    For Each s In str2
        If s.Contains("YourString") Then
            'add your line to txtbox
        Else
            'don't add your line to txtbox
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Or You Can Use

TextFile = TextFile.Replace("You want to Delete","")

Comment: This will leave blank lines in your file. You'll need to remove the entire line including the line break.

Comment: Then it'll be `TextFile = TextFile.Replace("You want to Delete", vbNewLine, b, 1, b.Length - 1)`, before that add `Dim b As String() = Split(TextBox1.Text, vbNewLine)`. Didn't tested it, but it should work, it replaces every "You want to Delete" with -1 line.