# How to remove specific lines of a file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I've got a file with a list of the names:

> Bill
>   Jack
>   Sam
>   Sarah

I want to be able to remove specific lines so if I asked it to remove "Jack" then the new list would become:

> Bill
>   Sam
>   Sarah

What I've got so far:

```
Imports System.IO
Dim filename As String = "C:\names.txt"
Dim StreamReader As New StreamReader(filename)
Dim LineCount As Integer = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Length

For i = 0 to LineCount - 1
    If StreamReader.ReadLine() = "Jack" Then
        'Remove This Line
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Re-write the entire file but skip the lines you don't want to write.  You aren't going to be able to do that when you are reading the file.

Comment: maybe this question can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755229/delete-specific-lines-in-a-text-file-using-vb-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get this down to one real line of code (not counting declaring the filename variable, since I could easily hard-code that):

```
Dim filename As String = "C:\names.txt"
File.WriteAllLines(filename, File.ReadAllLines(filename).Where(Function(l) l <> "Jack"))
```